# How to convey to a person what they think is correct

Tags: american-english, sentence-choice

If someone says it seems there is a lot going on your mind.
And I agree with it and feel that this person really has an insight into my mind.
How do I express this feeling to him ?

Should I say I agree with you
Or
I too think the same
Is there a better way to convey this ?
I relate with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I agree with you.

Perfect.

> <strike>I too think the same.</strike>

It's rather awkward and doesn't sound natural to me. We say

> I think so (, too).

> <strike>I relate with it</strike>

is incorrect. We say

> I can relate **to** that. = *I understand it because I've gone through a similar situation.*

Comment: "I agree with you" sounds to me as though you were agreeing with your friend's opinion about a third person. _You_ know what is going on in your own mind, so I think "Yes, there is" or "You're right" would be more appropriate.